# How to add javascript function in a zend dojo form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I'm fighting with a Zend_dojo_form.

Here is (part of) the code:

```
class Application_Form_RegistrationForm extends Zend_Dojo_Form {

    private $_user;
    private $_admin;
    private $_teamadmin;
    private $_newuser;
    private $_redirect;

    public function __construct($admin = false, $user = null, $redirect = '') {
        //blablabla
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init() {

        Zend_Dojo::enableForm($this);

        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAttribs(array(
            'id' => 'formRegistration',
            'name' => 'formRegistration',
        ));

        //some decorators

        if ($this->_admin) {
            $this->addElement(
                //blabla + inline javascript
                'onChange' => "if(this == ".E_UserRole::OPERATOR.") dojo.query(\".perms\").style({ display:\"block\" });  else dojo.query(\".perms\").style({ display:\"none\" }); "
                )
            );
        }

        if (Application_Manager_Login::hasRole(E_UserRole::ADMIN)) {
                //add some display:none elements
                $permission_decorators  = array(
                    "DijitElement",
                    "Errors",
                    array(array("data" => "HtmlTag"), array("tag" => "td", "class" => "perms", "style"=> "display:none", )),
                    array("Label", array("tag" => "td", "class" => "perms", "style"=> "display:none", 'escape' => false, 'requiredSuffix' => ' <span class="red">*</span>')),
                    array(array("row" => "HtmlTag"), array("tag" => "tr"))
                );

                //hidden element
                $this->addElement(
                    'CheckBox',
                    'permission_content',
                    array(
                        'decorators' => $permission_decorators,
                        'label'          => 'Gestione contenuti',
                        'checkedValue'   => true,
                        'uncheckedValue' => false,
                        'checked'        => $this->_user->permission_content,
                    )
                );      
        }
        //submit button and other stuff
    }
}
```

As you can see I've put some inline javascript to show/hide some options when the user_role changes.

Now the situation is a bit complex. I could keep writing inline javascript but **I'd like to declare a js function on the beginning** and just call it from the onchange Event.

Since this form is called by several controllers I won't add this function manually each time a

```
new RegistrationForm();
```

is called.

Comment: Can you not do this unobtrusively in an external JS file?

Comment: @TimFountain i found out the solution. Externalize the js was not what i wanted cause i'm not in a view. I'm going to write the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with this solution..

```
function addJavascript(){

        echo "<script>
        function toggle( e ){
            alert(e);
            if(e == ".E_UserRole::USER." || e == ".E_UserRole::ADMIN."){ 
                dojo.query(\".perms\").style({ display:\"none\" });
            }  
            else { 
                dojo.query(\".perms\").style({ display:\"block\" }); 
            }
        }   
        </script>
        ";

}
```

I declared this function inside the class and I just call it in the beginning with:

```
$this->addJavascript();
```

then in the onChange i call the toggle function I need (function that will become more complex, I need this workaround to make it readable) with:

```
$this->addElement(
       //blabla
       'onChange' => "toggle(this)",
       )
);
```

hope this helps someone else :)